# How to prevent proximity IR sensor reading when it's unplugged?

Tags: arduino, proximity, proximitysensor, arduino-c++

I'm working on the project with an IR proximity sensor and [my sensor's](https://5.imimg.com/data5/PH/XF/MY-45321773/ir-sensor-module-for-arduino-2f-rasberry-pi-500x500.jpg) digital output pin is LOW when the obstacle is a nearby sensor and it's HIGH when the obstacle is far away. The main problem is what happened when the sensor is unplugged, for now, it shows that obstacle is nearby, but for my project, it's not acceptable.

I solder one more wire on the sensor board and it's always HIGH when the sensor is plugged in, but this uses 2 gpio for one sensor and I can't get that kind of luxury, every gpio is important.

My code before adding new wire:

```
class ProximitySensor
{
    private:
        uint8_t _sensorPin;
    public:
        ProximitySensor(uint8_t sensorPin = 31) 
        {
            _sensorPin = sensorPin;
            pinMode(_sensorPin, INPUT);
        }
        bool OK()
        {
            if (digitalRead(_sensorPin) == LOW)
                return true;
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
};
```

So is there any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This is `C++` remove `C` tag

Comment: @Gox It's not really c++ either.

Comment: You cannot detect an unplugged sensor on a DigitalPin. If your sensor is like the image I think you can't do much about it because it has only digital output. But if it had an analog output, there would be some way to detect an unplugged sensor.